# AWS ApiGateway changed to LamdaRestApi , suporting proxy and custom model (form/urlencoded)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, infrastructure-as-code

So an outside resource hits the ApiGateway with form/urlencoded.  The ApiGateway was changed from DotnetLambda to LamdaRestApi.  All existing regular json posts to the api work and have no issue.

Slack had solved this issue here  http://www.ryanray.me/serverless-slack-integrations, but only manually via the web console for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' on aws gateway

Trying to use the existing IaC in typescript, to accomplish this.

Here is the code in which im trying to get to work.  I still need proxy: false for 'ANY' other endpoint as the same code below without any integratioinParms/LamdaIntegration keeps all other local api calls working.

The key is to have the ApiGateway to handle as it was working with proxy:true and a custom path and model which requires proxy: false which is complaining about.

```
export class DotNetRestApiCustom extends Construct {
  lambda: DotnetLambda;
  api: LambdaRestApi;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DotNetHttpLambdaApiProps) {
    super(scope, id);

this.lambda = new DotnetLambda(
  this,
  `${props.name}ApiLambda`,
  `${props.name}Api`,
  props.lambdaPath,
  props.functionHandler,
  props.functionProps,
  props.extraHashCodePaths
);

let domainName = props.fullDomainName ?? `${Utils.stage.toLowerCase()}.${props.domainTag}.internal.${props.dnsZone.zoneName}`;
if (!props.fullDomainName && props.internalDomain === false) domainName = `${Utils.stage.toLowerCase()}.${props.domainTag}.${props.dnsZone.zoneName}`;

this.api = new LambdaRestApi(this, `${props.name}Api4`, {
  proxy: false,
  // restApiName: `${Utils.stage}-${props.name}Api`,
  handler: this.lambda,

  domainName: {
    domainName: domainName,
    certificate: new Certificate(this, "Certificate", {
      domainName: domainName,
      validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(props.dnsZone),
    }),
    endpointType: EndpointType.REGIONAL,
    securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
  },
});

const msgResources = this.api.root.addResource("person");
const msgResource = msgResources.addResource("{personId}");

const methodResponse: MethodResponse = {
  statusCode: "200", 
  responseModels: {"application/json": Model.EMPTY_MODEL}
}

const integrationResponse: IntegrationResponse = {
  statusCode: "200",
  contentHandling: ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT
}

const requestTemplate = {
  //"field1"  : "$input.params('field1')",
  //or
  "body"    : "$input.json('$')",
}

const integrationParams = new LambdaIntegration(this.lambda, {
  allowTestInvoke: true,
  proxy: false,
  integrationResponses: [integrationResponse],
  passthroughBehavior: PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
  requestTemplates: { "application/json": JSON.stringify(requestTemplate) },
});

this.api.root.addMethod("POST", integrationParams, {
  methodResponses: [methodResponse],
});

new ARecord(this, "ApiDnsRecord", {
  zone: props.dnsZone,
  recordName: domainName,
  target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGateway(this.api)),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LamdaIntegration has and array of intergrationResponses, which you can add code inside responseTemplates.

```
const integrationResponse: IntegrationResponse = {
  statusCode: "200",
  contentHandling: ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT
  allowTestInvoke: true,
  proxy: false,
  integrationResponses: [
  {
     statusCode: "200",
     responseTemplates: {
     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": `
    #if ($context.httpMethod == "POST")
    ....rest of that code translation
```

`